# Como crear reporte matricial con arrays que tienen en común el índice

Tags: php

Tengo los siguientes arrays:

Array 1. Clientes:

```
Array 
(
    [1] => Jose Perez
    [3] => Pedro Paz
    [7] => Andres Juarez
    [9] => Jorge Hernandez
)
```

Array 2. Ventas por cliente tienda 1:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 10.00
    [7] => 15.00
    [9] => 30.00
)
```

Array 3. Ventas por cliente tienda 2:

```
Array
(
    [3] => 11.00
    [7] => 25.00
    [9] => 50.00
)
```

Intento hacer un reporte como el siguiente, en donde la ultima columna muestra el total de ventas por cliente, con foreach pero no he tenido éxito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ayuda please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como presentas esto (sin ningún tipo de código...) Esta mal, el índice no está bien definido y en la primera array el valor debería de estar entre comillas ("").

Aun así te voy a mostrar una posible solución, todo y que deberías demostrar que has hecho para probar que no te estamos haciendo una tarea...

Lo primero que deberás hacer es definir bien las array que vas a usar, una vez hecho eso vas a crear una 4ª array donde almacenaras toda la información.
Una vez preparado lo que vas a hacer es recorrer las arrays comparando los índices, si el primer índice concuerda con el/los siguientes que recorramos, meteremos este valor en la 4 array y acabaremos el bucle en el que nos encontramos, sino le daremos un valor de 0.00,para finalizar sumaremos ambas ventas y las mostraremos en formato de tabla.

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//vamos a crear un array con los datos de la tabla


$clientes = array (
    "1" => "Jose Perez",
    "3" => "Pedro Paz",
    "7" => "Andres Juarez",
    "9" => "Jorge Hernandez"
);

$ventas1= array(
    "1" => 10.00,
    "7" => 15.00,
    "9" => 30.00,
);

$ventas2 =array(
    "3" => 11.00,
    "7" => 25.00,
    "9" => 50.00
);

//vamos a crear una array donde asociemos las 3 array segun el indice
$ventas = array();
foreach ($clientes as $indice => $valor)
{
    foreach ($ventas1 as $indice2 => $valor2)

    {
        if ($indice == $indice2)
        {
            $ventas[$valor]["ventas1"] = $valor2;
            break;
        }else {
            $ventas[$valor]["ventas1"] = 0.00;
    }
    }
    foreach ($ventas2 as $indice3 => $valor3)
    {
        if ($indice == $indice3)
        {
            $ventas[$valor]["ventas2"] = $valor3;
            break;
        }else {
            $ventas[$valor]["ventas2"] = 0.00;
    }
    
    }
    $ventas[$valor]["total"] = $ventas[$valor]["ventas1"] + $ventas[$valor]["ventas2"];
}
var_dump($ventas);
echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr><th>Cliente</th><th>Venta 1</th><th>Venta 2</th><th>Total</th></tr>";
foreach ($ventas as $indice => $valor)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    //convertimos un valor en texto
    echo "<td>". $indice ."</td>";
    
    foreach ($valor as $indice2 => $valor2)
    {
        echo "<td>".$valor2."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Justamente así lo necesitaba, muchas gracias por la ayuda!, y una disculpa por no redactar el código como debe de ser.